# How can I keep track of multiple runs of the same function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function like this:

```
function run(arg) {
    if (!window.alreadyRun) init();
    window.alreadyRun = true;
    /* more code */
}
```

You get the idea, I'm trying to figure out if it's the first time a function is called.

Is there a better way to do this? Without using globals? Something like this:

```
function run(arg) {
    var ranAlready;
    if (!ranAlready) init();
    ranAlready = true;
    /* more code */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return a function, with a variable called `runCount` which will hold the number of times it was called.

```
var yourFunction = function() {
    var runCount = 0;

    return function() {
        console.log(runCount);
        runCount++;
    }  

}

var a = yourFunction();

a(); // runCount: 0
a(); // runCount: 1
a(); // runCount: 2
a(); // runCount: 3
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/jYm8U/).

If you just want to run an init type function, you could place the code above returning the inner function. It will be called once before returning the inner function, and its scope will retain to its outer function.

Comment: you mean **`var`** `runCount = 0;` right? else it's a global.


Works with var too. Awesome. Chalk one up for closures

Comment: @qwertymk I do have `var` there - it sets its scope to the `yourFunction`. If I used it in the inner function, it would reset its scope and it would be useless (always `0`).

Comment: Awesome exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ok fine, you did actually answer the question I asked, just not the question I meant to ask. I reposted what I want [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895283/keeping-track-of-multiple-runs-of-the-same-function-part-2)

Answer (score 2):

The power of closures.

```
var f = (function(run) {
    return function() {
        if (!run) init(),run=true;
        // do code
    };
}(false));
```

You can even use `if (!run) init() && run = true` and get `init` to return `false` if you want it to be called again on the next function call.

We have a self executing function which creates a local `run` variable and set's it to `false` by passing it in as an argument. We then have a single line which checks if it's `false` if so it does `init(), run=true` which is running the `init` function and assigning it to true in a single expression.

Basically anywhere were your using global scope to make the variable static to the function you can instead use a closure as a scope level between local function scope & global scope.

If you need a variable that is static to a function & read only you can use the little known `const` keyword.

Comment: `if (!run) init(),run=true;` does that work? Never seen JavaScript code like that before.

Comment: @Alex let me iterate that `a,b` statements kill readability and I check every use of it manually to see whether it's valid because I really don't trust it.

Comment: yep, http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.14 simply put, the engine evaluates each expression demarcated by the comma and returns the rightmost value (irrelevant in this case, since the result of `run=true` isn't assigned). In this case, `if(!run) { init(); run=true; }` is equivalent.

Comment: @harnish except it's use is mainly in single line if's where you want to avoid curly brackets.

Comment: @Hamish @Raynos Thanks guys. I'm not sure if I'll start using it, but it is always good to know :)

Comment: @Raynos I've mostly seen it as an optimization in `for` expressions, eg: `for(i = 0, j = someArray.length; i < j; i++) { }`

Answer (score 1):

I think closures are completely overkill for this, and only complicates the code.

What you're describing is known as a static variable in Object Oriented languages, and it can be mimicked quite easily in JS by attaching properties directly to the function. This is possible because functions are first-class objects in JS:

```
function run(arg) {
    if (!run.ranAlready) { // run.ranAlready is undefined at first, so falsy
       run.ranAlready = true;
       init();
    }

    /* more code */
}
```

This is far simpler than nested functions, and you can continue to use `run()` in exactly the same way.

Another advantage is that, for unit testing, you can still access the `ranAlready` property from outside the function to check that your code is working correctly:

```
assert(run.runAlready == false);
run();
assert(run.runAlready === true);
```

Granted, this can't be used for anonymous functions, such as in event handlers, but isn't it much cleaner to *give that anonymous function a name* instead of using nested functions and an extra function invocation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's just another way to do it. You can have the function modify itself. In the case below, `myfunction` gets changed to a new one. This *may* not be exactly what you're looking for but I think it's useful to at least post this so you can see alternative ways to do things (and also: self modifying code can just be cool at times).

```
var myfunction = function() {
    alert("This is the first time I'm executed");

    myfunction = function() {
        alert('Subsequent times');
    }
}

myfunction();  // displays the alert 'This is the first time...'
myfunction();  // displays the alert 'Subsequent times'
myfunction();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/wntmB/

Comment: this is a pain to do when using anonymous functions that don't really have access to themselves. I.e. passing anonymous functions as arguments to say `attachEvent`

Comment: @Raynos Definitely - I wouldn't recommend it for that sort of thing. Out of yours and Alex's answers, I don't claim it to be the best. I just think it's useful to know another technique :)

Comment: it's a nice technique especially if the function mutates a little differently at each call ;)